# Generating RSpec Examples via Functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to add a function to allow for quick testing of redirects for unauthenticated users. Here's what I have so far:

```
def unauthenticated_redirects_to redirect_path #yeild
  context "when not signed in" do
    it "redirects to #{redirect_path}" do 
      yield
      expect(response).to redirect_to redirect_path
    end
  end
end


describe SomeController do
  describe 'GET #show' do 
    unauthenticated_redirects_to('/some_path') { get :show }
    context "when signed in" do
      # One thing...
      # Another thing...
    end
  end
  describe 'GET #whatever' do
    unauthenticated_redirects_to('/some_other_path') { get :whatever }
  end
end
```

This doesn't work, however, since the scope and context of the primary `describe` block is not available to the block passed to `unauthenticated_redirects_to`. This reasonably leads to the error: `` undefined method `get' for RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:Class ``.

Is there a way around this or is there a cleaner way to accomplish something similar which I should consider?

Comment: Not sure why the answer went away, but this does seem like a fine application for RSpec's shared examples. Have you looked at that yet?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I have, but the use case didn't seem to match. After some pondering, I figured out how to do it. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18643980/390897).

Comment: Check out the couple of answers I added below. I didn't know about the metadata approach. I'm not exactly sure why the `before` approach doesn't suffer from the scope problem, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `shared_examples_for` seemed like overkill given that I was only concerned with a single example. Furthermore, `it_behaves_like("unauthenticated redirects to", '/some_other_path', Proc.new{ get :whatever})` seems unnecessarily verbose. The trick is to use `#send()` to maintain the proper scope.

```
def unauthenticated_redirects_to path, method_action
  context "when not signed in" do
    it "redirects to #{path} for #{method_action}" do
      send(method_action.first[0], method_action.first[1])
      expect(response).to redirect_to path
    end
  end
end

describe 'GET #new' do
  unauthenticated_redirects_to '/path', :get => :new
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using shared examples which triggers the example based on shared metadata (`:auth => true` in this case) and which parses the example group description to pick up some key parameters.

```
require 'spec_helper'

class SomeController < ApplicationController
end

describe SomeController, type: :controller do
  shared_examples_for :auth => true do 
    it "redirects when not signed in" do 
      metadata = example.metadata
      description = metadata[:example_group][:description_args][0]
      redirect_path = metadata[:failure_redirect]
      http_verb = description.split[0].downcase.to_s
      controller_method = description.match(/#(.*)$/)[1]
      send(http_verb, controller_method)
      expect(response).to redirect_to redirect_path
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #show', :auth => true, :failure_redirect => '/some_path' do 
    context "when signed in" do
      # One thing...
      # Another thing...
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #whatever', :auth => true, :failure_redirect => '/some_other_path' do
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's another shared examples approach, this time using a block parameter with a `before` call which avoids the original scope problem:

```
require 'spec_helper'

class SomeController < ApplicationController
end

describe SomeController, type: :controller do
  shared_examples_for 'auth ops' do 
    it "redirects when not signed in" do 
      expect(response).to redirect_to redirect_path
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #show' do
    it_behaves_like 'auth ops' do
      let(:redirect_path) {'/some_path'}
      before {get :show}
    end
    context "when signed in" do
      # One thing...
      # Another thing...
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #new' do
    it_behaves_like 'auth ops' do
      let(:redirect_path) {'/some_other_path'}
      before {get :whatever}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [rspec shared example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

Comment: I am sure shared example fits exactly in your case. I am using this in my project for the exact same case